# add hide_code to jupyter notebook

Tags: ipython, jupyter

I am trying to add the hide_code option to my ipython notebook (jupyter, version 4, python 2.7). It is supposed to add a button or an option to the cell pull-down menu that allows me to hide the code in my ipython notebooks. I have successfully run the 'pip install hide_code' command from the terminal (MacOS X El Capitan). I have restarted the notebook and expected to see a new I have tried to restart the notebook program but nothing happens. I am not computer savvy enough to know what to do from here. Did I miss something?

Here is the github repository for the code:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hide_code/0.3.0

Comment: Can you create a test notebook and show us what you have as an output?

Comment: Hi, Well, I just have the same notebook that I have always had. I mean from the documentation I got the idea that once I installed the package the notebook would now have the option to hide the code in particular cells, either with a button or from the dropdown menu. When I ran the pip install hide_code command again from my terminal I got the following message: Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): hide_code in /Users/michaelreinhard/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages. Is that relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the documentation: https://github.com/kirbs-/hide_code, you can troubleshoot by running the following code with appropriate Jupyter config directory location:

```
import hide_code.hide_code as hc
dir = "<full path to Jupyter config directory>"
hc.install(dir)
```

Comment: I tried running the command in the cell of a notebook with the path to the configuration directory specified as "/Users/michaelreinahrd/jupyter/" but I get back the message: "Starting hide_code.js install...
No config directories contain "custom" folder. Trying site-packages...
Using argument supplied path: /Users/michaelreinhard/jupyter/
Unable to install into /Users/michaelreinhard/jupyter/
Directory doesn't exist.
Make sure Jupyter installed.
Attempting to configure auto-loading for hide_code export handlers.
Jupyter already configured to auto-load export handlers."

Comment: The path at you are trying is incorrect. I can see you are using anaconda, please verify the path.

Comment: I tried installing it here: ```import hide_code.hide_code as hc
dir = "/Users/michaelreinhard/.ipython/"
hc.install(dir)``` output:
```Starting hide_code.js install...
No config directories contain "custom" folder. Trying site-packages...
Using argument supplied path: /Users/michaelreinhard/.ipython/
Copying hide_code.js to /Users/michaelreinhard/.ipython/
Attempting to configure custom.js to auto-load hide_code.js...
Custom.js not in custom directory.
Attempting to configure auto-loading for hide_code export handlers.
Jupyter already configured to auto-load export handlers.```

Comment: Is there some command I should run at the command line to 'verify the path'? Thanks. I know I am just hopeless with computers. Anyway, I'll close this question out since you have answered the basic question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

OK I found a way to do it.

1. Install hide_code... It will not work, though.
2. Try to install it with (with dir="~/.ipython" or whatever)

> ```
> import hide_code.hide_code as hc;
> dir = "<full path to Jupyter config directory>";
> hc.install(dir)
> ```

It will still not work, but it will copy a javascript file (hide_code.js) into that directory. We will use it in a bit.

3. Let's find where those nbextensions are. Find one of them. For example, keyboard_shortcut_editor:

> ```
> cd ~
> find -name keyboard_shortcut_editor
> ```

Mine finds it ./.local/share/jupyter/nbextensions/keyboard_shortcut_editor
Yours should be there too.

4. Go to that directory

> ```
> cd ./.local/share/jupyter/nbextensions/
> ls
> ```

You see full list of various extensions. Let's copy one of them into hide_copy:

> ```
> cp -r hide_input hide_code
> cd hide_code
> ls
> ```

5. The important file there is main.js. Replace it with that hide_code.js from ~./ipython

> ```
> cp ~./ipython/hide_code.js ./main.js
> ```

6. Rename hide-input.yaml with hide-code.yaml and edit the content accordingly. Mainly, replace all Hide_Input references to Hide_Code. You can edit readme.md as well, but that doesn't matter. Because, the main thing, you created a new extension.

Now, if you launch your jupyter and go to  http://localhost:8888/nbextensions, you will see Hide Code. And if click on that checkbox, it's on. Here are snapshots:

[image]

[image]

It is a weird sequence. But it worked for me. And the main thing, it puts it right where it needs to be. Hide_code actually needs to be a part of Nbextensions. I don't know why it is not. That way it's easy to turn it on and off any way you like it.

Comment: That made it work via MyBinder.org/Binderhub (fancy JupyterHub) sessions based on conda. Implemented [here](https://github.com/fomightez/jupyter_hide_code) so you won't need to.